# How to resolve this? HTTPConnectionPool Max retries exceeded (NewConnectionError Failed to establish new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed)

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping, python-requests, httpconnection

I'm trying to create a function that goes through all links it finds on a page, tests them to see if they return a 404 status code and then returns those that do from a list. However, as the title of this question suggests, I'm coming across an error which I am stuck on resolving. Here is the relevant part of the function in question:

```
def find_404(urlSoup):
   s = requests.Session()
   s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'My program'
   retry_strategy = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=1)
   adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy
   s.mount('http://', adapter)
   s.mount('https://', adapter)

   for link in urlSoup.find_all('a', href=True):
       search_links.append(link.get('href'))
   print(search_links)

   for search_link in search_links:
       try:
           if not search_link.startswith('#') and not search_link.startswith('/'):
               broken_query = s.get(search_link, allow_redirects=3)

               if broken_query.status_code == 404:
                   broken_links.append(search_link)

       except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
           print('Error: {0}'.format(exc))
```

The whole `requests.Session()` bit preceding the first `for` loop was added in an effort to resolve the error as some prior Stack Overflow posts I researched recommended that solution, but it hasn't fixed the error.
When I run the program with the above code (and a bit more which I left out of the above) I get the error mentioned in the title. I also don't think the function returns all the 404 pages it should be. I am using this page for testing because it links to various 404 pages:
https://optinmonster.com/best-404-page-examples/.

The above function only returns 5 404 links when I can tell from the page and the `search_links` list that there are other 404 pages it should probably be recognising.

Comment: maybe you open just too many connections at the same time.
you could try to modify connection pool settings in your e.g. https.conf. You should close connections immediately after and you can add a delay in your script to avoid this as a last but easiest resort.

Comment: @OliverPrislan Sorry, but may I ask how I modify the connection pool settings? I'm not sure how to close the connections in the settings as soon as possible.

Comment: I reviewed some other responses as the question wasn't new and they are pointing towards disabling certificate validation. `page = requests.get(url, verify=False)`  and mind the missing ")" in line `adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy`

Comment: @OliverPrislan That missing ')' in the adapter line is actually just a typo on this post, it doesn't exist in my code. I added the `verify=False` bit but unfortunately that doesn't resolve the error either. When I run the program I get the exact same error as well as a number of `InsecureRequestWarning` warnings.